# next export gives me an "Error occurred prerendering page"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, next.js

I know it's an usual error, but I can't find any problems in my code.

When I hit `next build` in my project, it's successful but I got an warning something like:

> Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to
> `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with
> getStaticProps

but in my `pages/_app` there is not defined the `getStaticProps` or `getInitialProps`.

`pages/_app.jsx`

```
class MyApp extends App {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.persistor = persistStore(props.store);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('__next').classList.add('loaded');
        }, 100);

        this.setState({ open: true });
    }

    
    render() {
        
        const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;
        const getLayout =
            Component.getLayout ||
            ((page) => <DefaultLayout children={page} />);
        return getLayout(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate
                    loading={<Component {...pageProps} />}
                    persistor={this.persistor}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default withRedux(createStore)(withReduxSaga(MyApp));
```

Then why this warning?

Also when I hit `next export` I get an lot of errors something like:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/vendor/vendor-store". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at S (/home/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:18:327)
    at Object.exports.useContext (/home/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:22:269)
    at Head (/home/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/head.js:170:34)
    at d (/usr/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/usr/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/usr/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (/usr/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (/usr/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:596:45)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/home/Desktop/abc/.next/server/chunks/9912.js:600:19)
```

How can I fix this one? Why is this error?

Comment: The `withRedux` HOC is most likely adding `getInitialProps` to you `_app`. Where does `withRedux` come from?

Comment: when i commented that line and just export default MyApp then when i hit next build then not showing that ``` getInitialProps``` warning . but also it's giving a error when i get before . ``` Error occurred prerendering page  .... ``` . so is it not only the problem is it ?

Comment: Looks like the warning you're seeing is not related to the second error you get. Do you get the same error when you remove `withRedux`? If not, can you please add the error to your question?

Comment: i got the same error when i remove withRedux .

Comment: The `Error: Minified React error` links to https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321, so verify all the scenarios mentioned there.